# ¿Por que cuando hago scroll a un panel se mueve el datepicker o select de combobox con el scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-datepicker

Tengo un panel con un scroll y dentro de ellos un datepicker y combobox, lo que sucede es q cuando hago scroll el datepicker y los select se  mueven con el scroll quedando  como en el aire

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código relacionado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay nada que no se resuelva con una buena descansada y luego una búsqueda en google, para el que le pase el mismo problema solo deben hacer overflow:visible y no overflow:auto, con overflow:visible no se moverá la tabla del datepicker de jquery junto con el scroll ni tampoco lo hará el combobox.

Comment: y acá esta donde encontré la respuesta https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker/issues/384

Comment: Hubiese colocado la imagen como se miraba antes y despues, pero la verdad aun no se como se colocan imagenes en este sitio